# Building Python 3.2 from source on Ubuntu 18.04, configure says: configure: WARNING

Tags: python, pip, compilation, python-venv

I have been trying to install Python 3.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 for sometime now. I have downloaded the source code and extracted the contents to the .tgz file with:
`tar xvf Python-3.2.6.tgz`.

Now after running:
`cd Python-3.2.6` and `./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install`, I get the following message after a long line of configure checks and passes:

`configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-optimizations, --with-ensurepip`

I want to build Python 3.2 from source with `pip` [and if possible, `venv`] included in the installation by default. Because of the configure warning, I am afraid that the build of Python 3.2 would not include Pip.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python comes builtin in with ubuntu. I don't see a reason why you would want to install an older version. But anyways here is how you create a virtualenv with Python 3.2 installed in it:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3.2 my_env
```

(Note: remember to change the name of my_env to whatever you want to name your env)

Then activate it:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Confirm the installation with the following command:

```
which python
```

or

```
which python3
```

You should receive a path

pip comes preinstalled in virtualenv